# There is a duplication of events ,when returning back

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have 2 `data-role="page"`  The first is formed (from json file ) , when you click on the entry pass for 2 page ( div ) , and there is more information about the recording

In second div , I have `<a data-rel="back" ><div class="back" >back</div></a>`

The problem is that first click it is working normally, it returns a page where all records . The second click , the process proceeds to block 1  , and then abruptly back to block 2, where a detailed information

**all records**

```
  $.getJSON('one.json', function(data, key) {
          var str = "";
          $.each(data, function(key, data) {
            str += "<div class='item' id='" + data.id + "' style='background: url(" + data.img + "/" + data.img + "); background-size: cover;'></div>";

          });
          $('#listlistbreakfast').html(str);
        });
```

**go to second page**

```
(document).on('tap', '.item', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    /*-----Плавный переход--------------------*/
    $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "mypage.html#recept", {transition: "fade"});
    /*----------Формирование на другой странице-------------*/

    $.getJSON(edaid+'.json', function(data, key) {

      var thisstr = "";
      $.each(data, function(key, data) {
        if (data.id == id) {
          thisstr += "<div class='personalimg' style='background: url("+data.img+"/" + data.img + "); background-size: cover;' >"+data.text+"</div>"; 
        }
      });
      $('#json').html(thisstr);
    });
  });
```

Comment: It is very hard to understand your need from your question.  If I understand correctly, you have a page that shows a list.  Each member in that list is clickable and leads to a details page.  Once there, you have a "back" button that leads back to the list. The issue is - when going to a details page, then going back to the list and then back to a details page again and clicking the back button - it goes to the list page and then to the details page again. Am I correct in this?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't delve too deep into the code but it seems as if each time you enter the details page, you recreate the `on` event.  Because of this, each time you click the button, it runs the function one more time.  This is why it would seem to you that it works "correctly" every other time.  So on every even number of entries to the details page, you would get the "wierd" effect.
Make sure the `(document).on('tap', '.item', function(e) {` is run only once and it will be resolved.

Comment: ,This not working, I try `$(document).on('tap', '.back', function(e) {
e.stopPropagation();
  $.mobile.back();
});` But now not event  I have `<a data-rel="back" ><div class="back" >back</div></a>`   ` data-rel="back" `

Comment: It is working.  Debug your code and put a break point on your `.on` statements.  See that they run several times.  Put a debug point inside their callbacks - see that they run several times with each click.

Comment: The event takes place 1 time,but link not work normal. I try `$('body').off('tap').on('tap', '.back', function(event) {
event.stopPropagation();
 $.mobile.back();console.log('1');
})` In console,i see one record `1`

Comment: I find problem, I removed all code from `$(document).on("pageinit", "body", function() {});`